# Как хранить несколько checkbox в БД?

Tags: поиск, sql

Допустим
4 параметра

бесплатно,100$,500$,1000$

Пользователь может выбрать от 1 до 4 параметра
То есть искать и где 100 и где 500 и где 1000.

1. Каким образом сохранить результат фильтра поиска?
2. 2 момент где лучше хранить настройки фильтра поиска в БД или на стороне клиента(cookie например)?

Единственное что приходит в голову это строка char символов, где каждый символ это параметр и если он 1 то включен, а если 0 то нет. Но это решение выглядит не очень, ведь если будут добавлены новые фильтры или удалены старые, то БД будет логически 'битая' из-за непонятности где какое смещение.
Как правильно сделать?

Comment: а что вам мешает хранить эту информацию в куках?

Comment: @DreamChild 
Забыл.) Там еще нужно учитывать интересы фильтра поиска другого человека. То есть определяется совместимость исходя из интересов другого.

Comment: какого другого?

Comment: Ну ищешь человека. У тебя есть предпочтения(фильтр поиска).
Но и у него тоже есть фильтр поиска, и если этот человек ищет не тебя, то релевантность будет ниже.
То есть при поиске учитываются 2 строки в БД первого и второго человека.

Comment: > Единственное что приходит в голову это строка char символов, где каждый символ это параметр и если он 1 то включен, а если 0 то нет.

Это хорошо, что вы дошли до маски своим ходом, но есть более эффективное решение - битовая маска, когда каждый флаг сохраняется как бит. Если интересно - гуглить битовые операции и bitmask.

> Но это решение выглядит не очень, ведь если будут добавлены новые фильтры или удалены старые, то БД будет логически 'битая'

Поэтому добавлять надо итерациями, в которые входит и обновление БД. Но, в принципе, можно и просто хранить текстом типа '100$' - (cont)

Comment: будет расходоваться лишнее место под БД, конечно, но вряд ли очень драматично.

Comment: можно например сериализовать массив с помощью serialize() и хранить в бд как строку